# Why is the number declared in the double function not used? (C)

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double calculate_average (int number)
{
    static int numberInput = 0; //counter
    static int sum = 0;
    sum = sum + numberInput;
    numberInput++;
    return sum / numberInput;
    // calculate and return average so far.
}
int main(void)
{
    double average;
    while (1)
    {
        int number;
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number == 0)
            break; //stops if number == 0
        else
            average = calculate_average(number);
    }
    printf("%.1f\n", average);
    return 0;
}
```

As I can personally tell, the function is trying to calculate the average. But why does the main function not use the `number` in the calculate_average function?

Comment: How did you confirm this?

Comment: You realize that `sum / numberInput` is integer division and will round toward 0?  The fact that the function is trying to return `double` is too late.

Comment: What does "call number" mean? What exactly do you think is missing? It's not clear. What input do you give this program? What output does it produce? Why is that wrong? [Edit] to include sample input, desired output, current output, and a description of the difference/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your `calculate_average` function does not use its given `number` argument because, *nowhere* in that function, do you *instruct* it to do so. Most likely, your `sum = sum + numberInput;` should really be `sum = sum + number;` (thus adding that given number to the running total).

A couple of other points:

1. You should initialize your `average` variable (to 0.0), otherwise you'll get a crazy result if you give your program an empty list (i.e. give zero as the first entry).
2. As your function returns a `double`, it is best to have the `sum` variable also as a `double`; otherwise, you are performing integer arithmtic in your calculation, and all returned values will be truncated to integers (losing any fractional parts).
3. Others will likely point out that you should *always* check the value returned by your `scanf` call (it will be `1` if the read operation succeeds) and add code to handle any error; however, addressing that point here is, IMHO, beyond the 'remit' of this question, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817178/10871073) to [How validate user input when the expected value is of type int and the entered value is not of type int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817098/10871073).

Here's a possible working version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double calculate_average(int number)
{
    static int numberInput = 0; //counter
    static double sum = 0.0;
    sum = sum + number;
    numberInput++;
    return sum / numberInput;
    // calculate and return average so far.
}

int main(void)
{
    double average = 0.0; // Always best to initialize variables!
    while (1)     {
        int getal;
        scanf("%d", &getal);
        if (getal == 0)
            break; //stops if getal == 0
        else
            average = calculate_average(getal);
    }
    printf("%.1f\n", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Please feel free to ask for any further explanation and/or clarification.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, this helped alot in terms of understanding what went wrong. The whole problem was actually the sum calculation that I fully ruined. 

So the fix was indeed sum = sum + number;

Comment: Point 3 is very important -- as written the code will probably hang (go into an infinite loop) if the user enters a non-digit (non-whitespace) character at any point.  Not good.  Much better would be at least `if (scanf("%d", &getal) != 1) break;` which will at least terminate the loop on an invalid (non numeric) input.

Comment: Woah, I just checked. And it indeed made it infinite. Thanks. Will have to lookout for these types of things now.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Indeed. But the linked answer (sort of) addresses that issue and I didn't really want to repeat other SO posts (I'm sure there are a few).

Comment: @Heeko The `scanf` family of functions were seemingly designed with the primary goal of 'tripping up' C beginners (and others)

Comment: No, they're designed to be powerful with a small footprint.  Following best practices (eg, if you're calling scanf in a loop, put the scanf call in the loop test) generally gets you clean code that does the right thing.